# How to input my API Token into Openrefine

Tags: opencorporates

I am trying to use [Opencorporate's reconciliation service](https://api.opencorporates.com/documentation/Open-Refine-Reconciliation-API) in [Openrefine](http://openrefine.org/). I have a paid API Token/Key.

Where would I input my API Token/Key?